# HBase 2.1.0 - CDH6.3.3 - Gradle Import fails

Tags: gradle, hbase

I tried import hbase 2.1.0 of cloudera 6.3.3 at my gradle file like this:

```
compile ("org.apache.hbase:hbase-client:2.1.0-cdh6.3.3"){
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j'
        exclude group: 'org.jruby'
        exclude group: 'jruby-complete'
        exclude group: 'org.codehaus.jackson'
        exclude group: 'org.codehaus.jettison'
    }
```

When I refresh the gradle , it shows below error:

```
Could not resolve org.apache.hbase:hbase-client:2.1.0-cdh6.3.3.
```

I tried refreshing gradle dependencies , but no luck

Any help appreciated! Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are in doubt about dependencies like this, use a repository aggregator like [mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/) and search for the module. You can find version 2.1.0-cdh6.3.3 of HBase Client [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase-client/2.1.0-cdh6.3.3):

[image]

As you can see from the description, the artifact is located in the Cloudera Maven repository, so you will need to configure that in Gradle:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/"
    }
}
```

Also, don't use the `compile` configuration as it is deprecated. Use `implementation` or similar instead.

Comment: Thanks, this saved me a lot of time, initially, I had put like below:

repositories {
    maven { url "http://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/" }
} 

then I noticed it is https instead of http :)